# Xamarin Studio source code windows not syncing up with Solution Explorer

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I am opening up a project in Xamarin Studio but the source files that I open in it are not kept synchronised to the Solution Explorer window.

How do I get the solution explorer window synchronised with the file that I am currently editing?

---

After a bit of investigation, it does sync, and keep the active document highlighted in Solution Explorer....

HOWEVER...

This does NOT work for files opened from a Shared Project.

Does anyone know how to get this to work with a Shared Project?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot? If you open a solution, you double click a file in the Solution Explorer and that shows the file content; what exactly does not work?

Comment: Yes - double clicking a file does open the document.  But when I have multiple documents open, I expect, just like in Visual Studio, for the document I've selected for the item to be 'tracked' / highlighted in the Solution Explorer window.  At present it is just showing the last document I've opened, and not keeping synced to the code editing window i'm going to be coding against.

Comment: After a bit of investigation, it does sync, and keep the active document open in Solution Explorer.... HOWEVER... This does NOT work for files in a Shared Project.  Does anyone know how to get this to work with a Shared Project?

Comment: Ok, what you want is: open a file from a shared project, open another file, select the first file in the tabs at the top of the text editor and it will not highlight the corresponding file in the solution explorer. This indeed does not work. You can file an enhancement at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com